# Moving character around on canvas but keping the character in the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a 2d game in JavaScript but my character can only move around the length of the screen so I was wondering if there was a way to make the canvas move but my character stay on the middle of the screen?

[This](http://billischill.ddns.net/gameQuest/move.html) is what I am trying to get it to work like, [this](http://billischill.ddns.net/gameQuest/game.html) is how terrible the game is right now, just because I was trying out a few game mechanics.

Here is my code for the test game

```js
            var audio = new Audio('billischill.ddns.net/gameQuest/sounds/theServerRoom.mp3');
            audio.play();


    // Create the canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    // Background image
    var bgReady = false;
    var bgImage = new Image();
    bgImage.onload = function() {
        bgReady = true;
    };
    bgImage.src = "billischill.ddns.net/gameQuest/images/gamemap.png";

    //computer
    var computerReady = false;
    var computerImage = new Image();
    computerImage.onload = function() {
        computerReady = true;
    };
    computerImage.src ="billischill.ddns.net/gameQuest/images/computer1.png";
    //hp box
    var hpBoxReady = false;
    var hpBoxImage = new Image();
    hpBoxImage.onload = function() {
        hpBoxReady = true;
    };
    hpBoxImage.src = "billischill.ddns.net/gameQuest/images/hpbox.png";
    // player image
    var playerReady = false;
    var playerImage = new Image();
    playerImage.onload = function() {
        playerReady = true;
    };
    playerImage.src = "billischill.ddns.net/gameQuest/images/char.png";

    // enemy image
    var enemyReady = false;
    var enemyImage = new Image();
    enemyImage.onload = function() {
        enemyReady = true;
    };
    enemyImage.src = "billischill.ddns.net/gameQuest/images/enemy_idle01.png";

    var computer = {
            wifi: true,
            x: 399,
            y: 200
        }
        // Game objects
    var hpBox = {
        restoreHealth: 34,
        x: 300,
        y: 300
    }
    var player = {
        hackingSkill : 10,
        stamina: 7,
        health: 100,
        sprintSpeed: 400,
        weakSpeed: 150,
        speed: 300 // movement in pixels per second
    };
    var enemy = {
        speed: 250,
        viewDistance: 40
    };
    var enemysCaught = 0;

    // Handle keyboard controls
    var keysDown = {};
    addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
    }, false);

    addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
    }, false);

    // Reset the game when the player catches a enemy
    var reset = function() {
        player.x = canvas.width / 2;
        player.y = canvas.height / 2;

        // Throw the enemy somewhere on the screen randomly
        enemy.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
        enemy.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
    };



    //w is 87
    //a is 65
    //s is 83
    //d is 68
    // Update game objects
    var update = function(modifier) {
        if (87 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
            player.y -= player.speed * modifier;
        }
        if (83 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
            player.y += player.speed * modifier;
        }
        if (65 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
            player.x -= player.speed * modifier;
        }
        if (68 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
            player.x += player.speed * modifier;
        }

        if (
            player.x <= (0)) {
            player.health -= 1;
            console.log('health decreasing');
        }
    }
    if (
        player.y <= (0)) {

        player.health -= 1;
        console.log('health decreasing');
    };

    // Are they touching?
    if (
        player.x <= (enemy.x + 32) &&
        enemy.x <= (player.x + 32) &&
        player.y <= (enemy.y + 32) &&
        enemy.y <= (player.y + 32)
    ) {
        ++enemysCaught;
        reset();
    }

    // Draw everything
    var render = function() {
        if (bgReady) {
            context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
        }
        if (computerReady) {
            context.drawImage(computerImage, computer.x, computer.y);
        }

        if (hpBoxReady) {
            context.drawImage(hpBoxImage, hpBox.x, hpBox.y);
        }
        if (playerReady) {
            context.drawImage(playerImage, player.x, player.y);
        }

        if (enemyReady) {
            context.drawImage(enemyImage, enemy.x, enemy.y);
        }

        // Score
    };

    function dieEvent() {
        player.health = 100;
    }

    function updateHealth() {
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.textAlign = "left";
        context.fillText("Health: " + player.health, 30, 32);
        context.fillStyle="#FF0000";
        context.fillRect(10,10,(player.health/100)*140,25);
        context.stroke();
    }
    function updateHackerSkill(){
        context.fillStyle = "green";
        context.textAlign = "left";
        context.fillText("Health: " + player.hackerSkill, 30, 32);
        context.fillStyle="#FF0000";
        context.fillRect(10,10,(player.hackerSkill/100)*1,45);
        context.stroke();
    }


    function isNearComputer() {
        if (player.y <= (computer.y + enemy.viewDistance + 23) &&
            player.y >= (computer.y - enemy.viewDistance) &&
            player.x <= (computer.x + enemy.viewDistance + 32) &&
            player.x >= (computer.x - enemy.viewDistance)) {
            console.log("near computer");
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.stroke();
            context.fillStyle = "green";
            context.font = "24px Helvetica";
            context.textAlign = "left";
            context.textBaseline = "top";
            context.fillText("Welcome to uOS v1.0 " , 20 ,10);
            window.setTimeout(500);
            context.fillText("user$> " , 20 ,35);


        }

    }



    function isNearHPBox() {

        if (
            player.y <= (hpBox.y + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
            player.y >= (hpBox.y - enemy.viewDistance - 64) &&
            player.x <= (hpBox.x + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
            player.x >= (hpBox.x - enemy.viewDistance - 64)) {
            console.log("healing!");
            if (player.health <= 100) {
                hpBox.restoreHealth = player.health - 100;
                player.health += hpBox.restoreHealth;
            }

        }

    }

        function moveEnemy() {
            if (
                player.y <= (enemy.y + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
                player.y >= (enemy.y - enemy.viewDistance - 64) &&
                player.x <= (enemy.x + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
                player.x >= (enemy.x - enemy.viewDistance - 64)) {
                console.log("seen on enemys Y");
                var audio = new Audio('sounds/theWanderer_Scream.m4a');
                audio.play();
                if (player.x >= (enemy.x)) {
                    enemy.x -= enemy.speed;
               }
                if (player.x >= (enemy.x)) {
                enemy.x -= enemy.speed;
                }
            }
        }

        function checkWallCollision() {
            if (player.y <= 0) {
                console.log("y")
                player.y += 64;
            }
            if (player.x <= 0) {
                 console.log("x")
                player.x += 64;
            }
            if (enemy.y <= 0) {
                console.log("y")
                enemy.y += 64;
            }
            if (enemy.x <= 0) {
                console.log("x")
                enemy.x += 64;
            }
        }

     //   function updateMouseCoords(){
     //           document.onmousemove = function(e){
     //           cursorX = e.pageX;
     //           cursorY = e.pageY;
     //            context.fillStyle = "green";
     //           context.font = "24px Helvetica";
     //           context.textAlign = "left";
     //           context.textBaseline = "top";
     //           context.fillText("x" + cursorX + "y" + cursorY , 20 ,10);
    //
     //       }
     //   }
     //   function drawViewLine(){
     //       var cursorX;
     //       var cursorY;
      //      context.beginPath();
       //     context.moveTo(player.x,player.y);
      //      context.lineTo(cursorX,cursorY);
       //     context.stroke(); 
       //     console.log("drawing line")
       // }
        function reducedSpeed() {
            player.speed = player.weakSpeed;
        }
        // The main game loop
            var main = function() {
            var now = Date.now();
            var delta = now - then;
            update(delta / 1000);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            render();
            updateHealth();
            moveEnemy();
            if (player.health <= 20) {
                reducedSpeed();
            } else {
                player.speed = 300;
            }
            if (player.health <= 0) {
               dieEvent();
            }
            checkWallCollision();
            isNearHPBox();
            isNearComputer();
            //updateMouseCoords();
            //drawViewLine();
            then = now;

               // Request to do this again ASAP
                requestAnimationFrame(main);
            };

            // Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
            var w = window;
            requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

            // Let's play this game!
            var then = Date.now();
            reset();
            main();
```

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
    <html>

    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas">
        </canvas>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the essence of your question.

Comment: sorry i just dont know what to take out and what will depend on if my character can move like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving character on canvas but not on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224795/moving-character-on-canvas-but-not-on-the-screen)

Comment: Looks mostly like a copy+paste of your last question?

Comment: im sorry i just really really want to learn this so i can show my parents but i  wasnt getting any help so i added a bit and figured it would get me somewere

Comment: Looks like you copy+pasted it three times yesterday too, so some good advice would be to slow down! Don't repost if you don't get an answer - a question rate-limiter may kick in if you get a lot of closed/downvoted questions.

Comment: okay sorry.... do you thnk you might be able to help me real quick with this